# JavaScript: Changing image in HTML with button

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have a problem with my code where I change an image by clicking a button in HTML, but when I try to run the code in the console it says it my image.src is undefined.

Comment: `document.getElementById("sider").innerHTML` returns a *string*, not the element

Comment: Similarly, `document.getElementById("sider").src="side1.jpg";` evaluates to a string, not the element. Put *just the element* into `image` instead

Comment: @Olivia You need this: `var image = document.getElementById("sider");`

Comment: @PrashantPimpale it still doesn't work

Comment: @Olivia Unable to reproduce :) Show the demo

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```
<p>
<img id="sider" src="side1.jpg" style="width:450px;height:650px;">
</p>


<center> 

<button type="button" onclick="changeImage()"> < </button>
<button type="button" onclick="changeImage()"> > </button>

<script>
var image = document.getElementById("sider").src;
var image_tracker = "1";

var side1 = 'side1.jpg';
var side2 = 'side2.jpg';

function changeImage() {

  if(image_tracker == "1") {
    document.getElementById("sider").src=side2;
    image_tracker = "2";
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("sider").src=side1;
    image_tracker = "1";
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var image = document.getElementById("sider");
var image_tracker = "1"

function changeImage() {
  if(image_tracker == "1") {
    image.src = 'side2.jpg';
    image_tracker = "2";
  }
  else {
     image.src = 'side1.jpg';
  }
}
```

And don't forget to put the images on the right path since you use a relative path here.